# pkill -f not working from inside shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I have a shell script called `kill.sh` that helps me restart a python script I've written. I normally use `pkill -f main.py` to kill my forever-running python script. However, when I wrote it into a shell script it does not work.

My script

```sh
pkill -f main.py
ps aux | grep main.py # Still shows the process running.
```

While just executing `pkill -f main.py` in bash command line works as expected. Why is this?

Comment: The time between you typing `pkill -f main.py` and then typing `ps aux | ...` in terminal is way longer then in a script and the process has no time to react.

Comment: @KamilCuk but I tried running kill.sh multiple times. The grep results all show the process still running

Comment: when you run your script is it showing any output , Indicating a process was killed ? how is that main.py is displayed in output of `ps aux | grep main.py`

Comment: I don't think it showed anything about the process being killed. I always had to check with ps aux. I have circumvented the problem for now by packaging it into a systemd service, so I'll just use systemctl to start and stop the service.

Comment: is main.py runnning under a different user than the shell user?

Comment: Does your kill script by any chance have a name which matches "main.py"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a satisfactory answer, as I cannot find out the root cause of why `pkill -f` does not work in a script. I ended up using a `systemd` Service file to manage my python process. Here's an example fyi.

```
[Unit]
Description=Service Name
[Service]
Environment=PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ExecStart=/path/to/python /path/to/python/script.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
WorkingDirectory=/python/project/dir/
```

Name the file `main.service` and place it in `/lib/systemd/system/`

- Running the service `systemctl start main.service`
- Stop the service `systemctl stop main.service`
- Restart the service `systemctl restart main.service`
- Show status and output `systemctl status main.service -l`

Now I don't have to worry about multiple processes running. If the program dies it'll even restart.

Comment: If you want to track down what `pkill` is doing, `sysdig` is an excellent tool for the job -- you can see exactly which signals were sent and delivered; you can actually watch the process tree scan; etc.

Comment: ...that said, using a systemd service as you are is absolutely the Right Thing, so by no means let me persuade you to revert.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks, I’ll keep that in mind. I just need my service functional so I’ll just leave this be to save time. I think another solution may be to have a PID file and use kill -9 PID. It may be more accurate.

Comment: I _strongly_ advise sticking with systemd over using a pidfile -- and `kill -9` is hazardous; f/e, it prevents unflushed content from being written to stdout (which, unlike stderr, is buffered by default when not pointed to a TTY) or to open files.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Found that script was edited in windows and end of line had that extra character, and it was messing with pkill.
Just edited script in Linux editor, works fine now.